How to scroll and paginate together
I use is rowModelType: 'infinite' Can ag-grid scrolling be combined with custom paging, updating the current page number of the pager in real time during scrolling, then how do you know the current page number during scrolling up, by starRow calculation like scrolling down triggers getRows, or some other method;
If you skip directly to page 5, how should the ag-grid data be handled without affecting scrolling up or down
v25.0.1
Can someone help with this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
